# iOS8 UISearchController Covers Up UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

I've implemented a 1UISearchController1 for my tableview, with scopes and everything. However it doesn't display correctly when the view loads initially.

There are four different things I see depending on my actions.

This is what I see when the view first appears. I wouldn't expect the scope bar to appear:

[image]

Now, if I click on the search bar, I see this:

[image]

Next, if I click on the Cancel button again, I see this on the table view:

[image]

Finally, if I tap on the search bar again, I see what I would expect when I tapped on the search bar the first time:

[image]

And if I cancel one more time, now the search bar displays correctly on the table view:

[image]

Here's the relevant part of my TableViewController.

```
class BaseWineTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    func ConfigureSearchController() {
        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.resultSearchController.delegate = self

        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .None
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", CELLAR_STATUSES.Cellared, CELLAR_STATUSES.Wishlist, CELLAR_STATUSES.Finished]

        self.resultSearchController.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ConfigureSearchController()
    }
```

Comment: try to configure the `self.resultSearchController.searchBar` inside the `viewWillAppear:`method instead of  `viewDidLoad`. my explanation is that those also deal with layout, which is not a good thing to mess with on `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I think it has something to do with initializing the search controller in viewDidLoad too but I don't know where else to initialize it.

Comment: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar` try to put this line on a `viewWillAppear` or `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Tried this as well but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. When I removed this line:

```
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
```

But left in the line that defines the scope titles, it fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it seemed to occur only in iOS8. In iOS9 the searchbar did not cover the tableview.

I am not using the scope bar, so the proposed fix was not applicable to me.

When adding the line

```
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

before assigning the searchBar to the tableview, it worked fine in both iOS8 and iOS9 for me.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```